# Login with lightOpenID and yahoo

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I have tried to create an openid login form with https://gitorious.org/lightopenid library , but doesn't work with yahoo openid url.
The error reported fro the library is : No OpenID Server found at https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid20/www.yahoo.com/xrds

Can you help me about this problem?

Thanks to all in advance,
  Cris

P.S. The library work fine with google openid.

Answer (score 0):

Use $openid->identity = 'https://me.yahoo.com'; for Yahoo